# Open soft keyboard for ListAdapter item with contains a view with a string

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a ListAdapter with in this case contains a single item.
That item produces a view that has an EditText.

When the view get displayed I want to open the soft keyboard to allow the user to edit the field.

I tried to call in the getView() function of the adapter:

```
View edittext = view.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
edittext.requestFocus();
mInputMgr.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

which doesn't seem to do anything.

I also tried:

```
View edittext = view.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
edittext.requestFocus();
mInputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

That produces for some mysterious reason a loop in which the softkeyboard gets opened and closed repeatably.

When I remove the requestFocus and touch click on the EditText in the program it pops up the softkeyboard but regardles of whether requestFocus is there showSoftInput doesn't seem to work.

What do I have to do?

XML of the list element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:focusable="true"
  android:background="@color/light_blue"
  >

<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="" 
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:inputType="textShortMessage"></EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML that contains the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

long getView function:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView != null){
        return convertView;
    }

    if (mDialog!=null){
        final Choice thisChoice = mDialog.getChoice(
                position, 
                mContentRes);
        Log.v(TAG, "DialogAdapter: "+ thisChoice.toString());

        View view = thisChoice.getView(
                mInflater, parent, mFillInput, mDialog);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (thisChoice.choiceSingleClick(mDialog)){
                    Log.i(TAG, 
                            "Single Click selected Choice: " 
                            + thisChoice.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, 
                            "getNextInputId: " 
                            + Integer.toString(
                                    thisChoice.getNextInputId()));
                    mFillInput.renderNext(thisChoice.getNextInputId());
                }
                else{
                    mFillInput.checkSelectedStatus();
                }
            }
        };
        view.setOnClickListener(listener);

        View.OnLongClickListener longListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {            
                thisChoice.choiceLongClick(mDialog);
                return false;
            }
        };
        view.setOnLongClickListener(longListener);

        Log.d(TAG, "thisChoice: " + thisChoice);
        Log.d(TAG, "selected: " + thisChoice.isSelected());
        if((position == 0 && mDialog.getSelectedCount() == 0) ||
                thisChoice.isSelected()){
            view.requestFocus();
        }


        if (thisChoice.isEnterStringChoice() & position==0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Request Focus for StringChoice");
            View edittext = view.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            edittext.requestFocus();
            //edittext.dispatchTouchEvent(null);
            //FillInput.mInputMgr.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            //mFillInput.mInputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
        }

        return view;
    }           
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which SDK version are you targeting?

Comment: Also, the XML and/or Java you're using to generate your ListAdapter would be useful.

Comment: @ianside: I would like to have it work in 1.5 but if you have something that only works later I would also be interested.

Comment: Try in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289335/soft-keyboard-shows-up-on-edittext-focus-only-once/7291121#7291121) way.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)` on the `EditText` ?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't recognise     edittext.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent); as a valid comment. Did you mean something different?

Comment: @Christian: you need to create the `MotionEvent`.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

try to set `android:focusable="true"` in xml or `setFocusable(true)` in java code on your TextEdit control

Comment: This doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `<RelativeLayout />`. That is sometimes needed to make it so that widgets in lists get the right focus.

Comment: err, I believe I mean `afterDescendants` instead of `blocksDescendants`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `<requestFocus />` into your `EditText`:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:inputType="textShortMessage">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Or you can right click on the `EditText` in design mode, select `Request Focus`. Hope it will work...