# Soft Keyboard shows up on EditText focus ONLY once

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

Thanks for reading.

I am facing a strange problem: My app behavior is such that when the `Activity` starts, I `requestFocus()` on an `EditText` and show the soft keyboard.

However, when I press the back button to dismiss the keyboard and tap the `EditText` I don't get the keyboard to pop up ever again. Only way out is to the start the `Activity` again.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(imm != null) {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);    
        }
```

And here's my XML:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch" android:hint="Test Hint"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:maxLength="30"> 
</EditText>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try to open and hide inside a `Runnable` as,

**TO OPEN**

```
                 ettext.requestFocus();
                 ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        keyboard.showSoftInput(ettext, 0);
                    }
                },200);
```

**TO CLOSE**

```
                    ettext.requestFocus();
                    ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ettext.
                                                         getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                },200);
```

Comment: That worked! I just used the Open Keyboard code though. I just hit Back key to hide the keyboard. Thanks! :)

Comment: Works on SDK 17 / MIN 8 / TARGET 17!

Comment: I've done this same solution before I arrived at this page - but I just wanted an explanation on why our solution works

Answer (score 6):

You used the wrong view for showing the input window.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null) {
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I just corrected it. It was a typo while framing the question. But original code has correct view.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)EnterWordsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null)
    {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(YOUE_EDTITE_TEXT.SHOW_FORCED,1);
    }
```

Comment: You mean imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 1); right? If yes, that didn't work :( Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SagarHatekar You might have added something to your manifest. I have already try it out many times. It work proper.

Answer (score 1):

None of above work until i clear the forces `textField.clearFocus();` before requesting focus, so my final code in `onResume` looks like this.

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ");
        resumed = true;
        textField.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textField.clearFocus();
                textField.requestFocus();
                if (!editMode)
                    textField.getText().clear();
                inputMathodType = SharedPref.read(SharedPref.KEY_INPUT_MATHOD_SHARED_PREF, -1);
                setInputMethod();

            }
        }, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this coding in your Activity,It will hide your keyboard     `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problems for days. Solutions provided with creating threads and delays in the code are not efficient. The framework has solution. you can check my short solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74442682/6906562