# How do I prevent the software keyboard from popping up?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have my own keypad in my application so I want to hide the software keyboard all the time(in specific activities & dialogs).
I experimented with two options:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This code prevent the keyboard from popping up at the beginning, but when I click on the textbox the keyboard still pops.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This code hide the keyboard, but it doesn't prevent the keyboard from popping up.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289335/soft-keyboard-shows-up-on-edittext-focus-only-once/7291121#7291121

Comment: thx but I am having a different issue there... I want to hide the keyboard from the very beginning and prevent it from popping up no matter what I do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured out!

I used

```
public void supressKeyboard() {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 
}
```

for the activities where I want to suppress the keyboard(you can put it in a general activity where all other activities inherit from)

But this won't prevent the keyboard from popping up when you click on the EditText textbox. What I did is I consumed the onTouch event for the text box:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is the technique I use too

Comment: How do you get the cursor to show, or do you? Whenever I swallow the touch event it prevents the cursor from showing.

Comment: This post is old, but... I was wondering, can you still type in with a hardware keyboard?