# How to set keyboard in password-type mode on start of the Activity?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm using the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` command for drawing keyboard at the beginning of the Activity and it works just as I want it to work with 2 slight problems - swype-typing is enabled and so is the word prediction and I want to prevent it from happening. I thought maybe setting keyboard in `passwordText` input mode may solve the problem but I cannot find anywhere how to do it. Is there any method that will allow me to show keyboard in `passwordText` mode on start of the Activity?

Also I should add that I'm looking for the way of doing that in such a way, that the keybord won't show when app is ran on device with physical keyboard (that's why I used XML declaration in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Edittext in xml:

android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"

or in code:

edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Comment: I don't have any EditTexts, I'm handling keyboard input in Activity, and as I said I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` in AndroidManifest in order for keyboard to appear the problem is it allows swyping and shows suggestions and I need to change it without using any EditTexts. (To handle keyboard input I'm using `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` methods in Activity)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the first question, AFAIK you set the textfield to password mode, not the keyboard, like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/password"
android:hint="@string/password_hint"
android:inputType="textPassword"
... />
```

More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Now, about preventing the keyboard from appearing on a device with physical keyboard, I recomend you check this answer:

[How do I prevent the software keyboard from popping up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665685/how-do-i-prevent-the-software-keyboard-from-popping-up)

Comment: the thing is I don't have any EditText fields, as I'm handling entire keyboard input from the activity and I want it to stay that way.