# Prevent popping of default keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an edit text box and my own layout for keyboard, I prevented the popping up of default keyboard using this link

> [How do I prevent the software keyboard from popping up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665685/how-do-i-prevent-the-software-keyboard-from-popping-up)

but it is disabling the cursor and click on the edit text which i want for copy paste . Please help .

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This code doesnt work when i click on the edit text box. On clicking edittext, keyboard still pop up

Comment: where did you put it?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.LiveStreamActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_live_stream"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Comment: Not working . KEyboard still comes when i click on edit text box. I am trying on android 4.4.4