# AnySoftKeyboad stays with garbage data after I hide it

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a problem which occurs only when I use AnySoftKeyboard.
I'm trying to show/hide the keyboard according to EditText focus.
I used the methods I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

When I'm hiding the keyboard, there is a strange behavior -

- When I rotate the screen, the text that was in the EditText is doubled.
- I thought that it has to do with the onCreate method, but I can see the it happens also when I click "back" (Finish()). I see it for a split second before the Activity is closed.
- When I start a new activity, (ActivityB from ActivityA) then clicking "Back" once doesn't do anything (probably "closing" the invisible keyboard).
- When I click "back" again, ActivityB closes but I can see for a split second the text from ActivityA keyboard in a big font across the screen (like a 100 millisecond pop-up )

Does anyone has an idea how to deal with it?

Comment: Show your code quote your exact problem...

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289335/soft-keyboard-shows-up-on-edittext-focus-only-once/7291121#7291121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug in  AnySoftKeyboard. 
I didn't happen when I use other keyboards.

I solved it by doing setText to the EditText view before hiding it - its probably resets some stuff on keyboard object.

Here is my code:

```
        View view = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view==null)
            return;

        IBinder binder = view.getWindowToken();
        if (binder == null)
            return;

         // I used this to fix the strange behaviour
        if (view instanceof EditText)
            ((EditText)view).setText(((EditText)view).getText().toString());


        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binder, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Surprisingly it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```