# how to hide softkeyboard in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, hide, android-softkeyboard

I am using the Edit Text field in my application. when i click on it the soft keyboard appears.but when i click on the "DONE" button (which is on soft keyboard ),it should be disappear but it does not disappear.i set the input type as text in the layout file.I want to hide the soft keyboard when i press button.
please help.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
public class locupdate extends MapActivity implements OnDoubleTapListener{

    GeoPoint p,geoPoint;
    MapView SearchMap;
    List<Overlay> list;
    MapController map_controller;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location,update_location ;
    MyLocationOverlay me;
    Button go_btn,done;
    String city;
    int cid;
    Double lat_update,lng_update;
    EditText location_entered;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bingmapupdate);
        go_btn=new Button(getApplicationContext());
        go_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button);

        location_entered=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterLocationforSearch); 
        location_entered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                location_entered.setText("");

            }
        });
        done=new Button(getApplicationContext());
        done=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_locationUpdateDone);
        done.setEnabled(false);
        done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                String memberid=preferences.getString("unique_userName", null);

                String lat=Double.toString(lat_update);
                String lang=Double.toString(lng_update);
                editor.putString(memberid+"LATITUDE",lat);
                editor.putString(memberid+"LONGITUDE",lang);
                //editor.putLong(memberid+"LATITUDE",lat_update);
                //editor.putLong(memberid+"LONGITUDE",lng_update);

                editor.commit();
                //editor.putString("Location", update_location);

                //update the "lat_update" , "lng_update" and "update_location" with UID(cell_id)

                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClassName("some pkg name here", "some activity name here");
                startActivity(i);

                finish();

            }
        });

        SearchMap= (MapView)findViewById(R.id.View_map);
        //SearchMap.setTraffic(true);
        SearchMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map_controller=SearchMap.getController();
        SearchMap.setClickable(false);
        map_controller.setZoom(10);

        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = SearchMap.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);     
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        geoPoint=new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1e6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1e6));
        p=geoPoint;

        // map_controller.animateTo(geoPoint);

        // SearchMap.invalidate();

        go_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                location_entered=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                location_entered=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterLocationforSearch);

                String area=location_entered.getText().toString();
                BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this.changeMap(area);
                SearchMap.setClickable(true);

            }
        });

    }

    protected class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas,MapView map,boolean shadow,long when){

            p=geoPoint;
            //map_controller.animateTo(geoPoint);
            Paint paint=new Paint();
            super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
            Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
            map.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
            canvas.drawText("I am here...", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event,MapView SearchMap)
        {   
            //Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this,
            //  "Touch Event Listener called",
            //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SearchMap.setClickable(true);

            drawMarker(event);
            done.setEnabled(true);

            return false;
        }

    }/*--------------------------------------end of overlay class------------------------------------*/
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        drawMarker(event);
        Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this,
                "onDoubleTap called",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        drawMarker(event);
        Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this,
                "onDoubleTapEvent called",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        drawMarker(event);
        Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this,
                "Single Tap Event Listener called",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    /*-------------------------------------------get clicked location and draw marker---------------------------*/
    public void drawMarker(MotionEvent event){
        GeoPoint p = SearchMap.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*save these latitude and longitude*/
        lat_update=p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
        lng_update=p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6;

        //lat_update=(long)(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
        //lng_update=(long)(p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6);

        int X = (int)event.getX();          
        int Y = (int)event.getY();
        geoPoint = SearchMap.getProjection().fromPixels(X, Y);
        //map_controller.animateTo(geoPoint);

        //int lac = cellLocation.getLac();


        // me = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), SearchMap);
        getLocationName(p);

    }
    /*-----------------------------------getLocationName method----------------------------------------*/
    public void getLocationName(GeoPoint point_city){
        float latitude = point_city.getLatitudeE6() / 1000000F;
        float longitude = point_city.getLongitudeE6() / 1000000F;

        location.setLatitude(latitude);
        location.setLongitude(longitude);

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()) ;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(point_city.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 , point_city.getLongitudeE6() /1E6, 1);
            //addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,5);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                city=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String state=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            String sb;
            sb=city+""+state+""+country;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sb,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        location_entered.setText(city);
        /*save city in shared preferences*/
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("city",city);
        editor.commit();

    }

    /*-------------------------------------------Change Map Method---------------------------------------*/

    public void changeMap(String area)
    {

        GeoPoint myLocation=null;

        double lat = 0;
        double lng = 0;
        try
        {

            Geocoder g = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

            List<Address> result=g.getFromLocationName(area,5);
            if(result.size()>0){

                //Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this, "country: " + String.valueOf(result.get(0).getCountryName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                lat = result.get(0).getLatitude();
                lng = result.get(0).getLongitude();
                myLocation=new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1e6),(int)(lng*1e6));
                map_controller.animateTo(myLocation);

            }            
            else{
                Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this, "record not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            Toast.makeText(BingMapLocationUpdateActivity.this, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);

        map_controller.setZoom(12);
        //SearchMap.invalidate();
    }


}
```

my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bingmapupdate_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Google Maps"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bingmapupdate_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enterLocation_label"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="search" >
    </EditText>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/View_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:apiKey="GOOGLE_API_KEY" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ng"
        android:text="Go" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_locationUpdateDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ng"
        android:text="DONE" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enterLocation_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Enter City"
        android:textColor="#111111" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289335/soft-keyboard-shows-up-on-edittext-focus-only-once/7291121#7291121

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this function:

```
public static void hideSoftInput(Context ctx)
{
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(new View(ctx).getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

---

For your particular case, you can use this:

```
    location_entered.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                // code to hide the soft keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

after this part on your **onCreate**:

```
  location_entered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  [...]
```

Comment: how do i call any method when i press done button from soft input keyboard? it must hide when i click done on soft input keyboard....

Comment: It's weird that Done button doesn't hide it automatically. I tried in my app and it does. Can you add your layout?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="search"
 android:layout_width="170dp" android:id="@+id/enterLocationforSearch"
 android:inputType="text"
 android:layout_below="@+id/bingmapupdate_label" android:singleLine="true"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/go_button" 
 ></EditText> </RelativeLayout>

Comment: Can you add it to your question? Also, is there no button on that layout?

Comment: I added my XML file,plz have a look. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this...

```
      getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```