# no keypad for edittext in android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

In my project I am not getting the keypad for `EditText` but if I type using the keyboard I am able to add the data but in emulator not keypad is visible.

Went to through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098016/edittext-not-showing-a-keyboard) post and made changes but no luck.

my XML file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Brokerage Detail" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="AddStock" />
```

Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Edit your AVD and set both :

`Keyboard Lid Support` and `Keyboard Support` to `YES`

Then restart your AVD. May be it will work.

See avd image below:-

[image: avd pic]

**EDIT :  To enable soft keyboard in Genymotion**

Go to `Settings` -> `Language & input` and open the `Default` item under `Keyboard & Input Methods`. There is a `Hardware` setting that you can toggle on/off. When it is **on** you use your physical keyboard and when it is **off** the standard soft keyboard should pop-up whenever a text field gets focus.

Comment: Thanks @Shylendra I am using `Genymotion` emulator where will be the control for that