# Android Edittext doesnt open keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

In Android applications , Defaultly , when click or focus on edittext , the system keyboard opens. But in my app, keyboard doesnt show. Why ?

**Layout code  :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_padding"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/login_padding">

<!--<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:background="#fff"-->
    <!--android:padding="4dp">-->

<!--</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>-->


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"

            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"

            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"

            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:background="@drawable/buttontype1"
                android:textColor="@color/loginScreenButtonTextColor"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:background="@drawable/buttontype1"
                android:textColor="@color/loginScreenButtonTextColor"
                android:layout_weight="0.4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/forgot_my_password"
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**some part of AndroidManifest.xml**

Dont attempt to say you used **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"** . I used it because it hides keyboard on activity start.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"

        android:theme="@style/MyLibrary">
        <activity android:name=".main.SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/MyLibrary" />
        <activity
            android:name=".login.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password" />
        <activity android:name=".login.ForgotPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity" ></activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Add this `android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your `Edit Text`.

Comment: are u using emulator because in emulator keyboard will not open ?

Comment: @KastriotDreshaj it is open . Dont worry.

Comment: @jaydroider -1 for redundant answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText not showing a keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098016/edittext-not-showing-a-keyboard)

Comment: No duplicate it doesnt work. My problem is different

Comment: Isnt there anyone to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem . I removed **android:textIsSelectable="true"**  from edittexts . It worked

Comment: This is so random. Android really should clean up its act when it comes to soft-keyboard management.